# file sharing in chatting using Pubnub Android

Tags: android, pubnub

Can you please tell me how to implement file sharing in chatting using PubNub in Android. I searched lot of things but there is no example. 
PubNub implements only text chatting.

Comment: you are using PhoneGap ??

Comment: No I am using native (Java) Android

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub File Sharing Best Practices

It is best practices to upload the file to a scalable, hosted file system (Amazon S3, Box, Dropbox, Drive, etc.) and then send the file URI via PubNub to share that file.

Here are some links you may also find informative:

- [KB Article: Is it possible to send big payload via PubNub messages, e.g. audio, images, video, etc.?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/416/can-i-send-large-messages-with-pubnub)
- [Can I stream binary data through PubNub?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/411/can-i-stream-binary-data-through-pubnub)
- [DIY Snapchat: Capture and Send Images with JavaScript](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-08-28-diy-snapchat-clone-capture-send-images-javascript-tutorial/)